# Questions in collectives are miscounted

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives

I believe a screenshot speaks a thousand words:

[image]

<s>My guess is the discrepancy is due to deleted questions.</s> [Never mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)

Comment: But there are 62.1k non-deleted questions tagged with [tag:go]...

Comment: (1/2) The numbers for the sidebar and question list come from different sources, so small disparities are to be expected. That being said, there are other factors responsible for the big gap you're seeing. One being closed questions, which don't appear in the question list but are still counted by the sidebar.

Comment: (2/2) Another being a lower limit on the answer-score for eligible questions, with the sidebar being less restrictive and resulting in a bigger number of results. Besides these two, there are some known-but-not-yet-fully-understood issues that also contribute to what you're seeing. We're looking into all of these and hope to have at least a partial fix, to bring the numbers closer together, Soon™